# Azure Search - order by expression

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We would like to know, whether Azure Search makes possible undermentioned scenario.

Let us have an Azure Search index with three columns:

```
1.  Id [Edm.String]
2.  Tags [Collection(Edm.String)]
3.  MaxScore [Edm.Int32]
```

The index contains the following two entries:

```
Id  Tags                MaxScore
1   Paris,London,Rome   30
2   Paris               10
```

We have also a scoring profile and a scoring function of type Tag (Sum, Linear) which evaluate every tag by 10 points (boost = 10).

We want to search the records with tags "Paris, London" in this index and sort it according to the **percentage of compliance**, while 100% is the value in column MaxScore.

The problem is that by default Azure Search sorts records by score. So the results are following:

```
Id  Tags                MaxScore    Score     %
1   Paris,London,Rome   30          20        67%
2   Paris               10          10        100%
```

But we need to sort the records in descending order by the [%] column. It would be enough to makes possible Azure Search sorts records by expression. It would be something like $orderby=score*(100/MaxScore) in our case. However this is not currently possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search does not support this scenario at this time. Please consider adding an item to our [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) site for supporting expressions in `$orderby`. Also, please vote on [this suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328693-sort-results-by-rank) to support explicitly sorting by score in `$orderby`.

Answer (score 1):

I did sorting based on date columns, hope this might be helpful.
Here I am using .NET SDK if required the same options available in REST API also.

```
public async Task<DocumentSearchResult<Documents>> FileSearchResultsAsync(SearchRequest searchRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters()
            {
                SearchMode = SearchMode.Any,
                Facets = new List<String>() { "state,count:25,sort:value",
                                             "fileType,count:25,sort:value"
                                            },
                Top = 10,
                Skip = searchRequest.PageNumber > 1 ? searchRequest.PageNumber * 10 : 0,
                OrderBy = searchRequest.SortOrder == SortOrder.Recent ? new List<string> { "pubDate desc" } : new List<string> { "" },
                IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
                Select = new List<string>
                {
                    "fileName",
                    "state",
                    "fileType",
                    "pubDate"
                },
                Filter = BuildFacetFilter(searchRequest)
            };

            return await searchConfig.IndexClient.Documents.SearchAsync<Documents>(searchRequest.SearchQuery, sp);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```